# Unexpected closing tag | angular2.5 | custom tags

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

```
<someTag data_value="somevalue" class="card">
    <div class="some" *ngFor='let item of tempData'>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.id }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.name }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.status }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.sent }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.views }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.clicks }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.source }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.created }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.report }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue"><hr></someTag>
    </div>
</someTag>
```

When I use this code inside my main component's html file, I get the following error:

```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
> Unexpected closing tag "sometag". It may happen when the tag has
> already been closed by another tag. For more info see
> https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
>               <sometag data_value="somevalue"><hr></sometag>
>           </div>  [ERROR ->]</sometag>"): ng:///someModule/someComponent.html@65:1
```

but when I make a new component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'some-list',
    styleUrls:['some.component.css'],
    template: `
        <div class="some" *ngFor='let x of data'>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.id }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.name }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.status }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.sent }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.views }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.clicks }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.source }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.created }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
                <span class="fs-6">{{ x.report }}</span>
            </sometag>
            <sometag data_value="somevalue"><hr></sometag>
        </div>
    `,
})
export class ListComponent{
    @Input() data;
}
```

and use the above new component inside the main component's file,

```
<someTag data_value="somevalue" class="card">
     <some-list [data]="tempData"></some-list>
</someTag>
```

It works without error.

> Question:-
>        What could be the possible reason for this?

Yes :- 
 I checked end tags.
 I counted end tags.
 I don't have any unclosed tags since the new component is just a copy paste of this loop code.

Comment: Try <hr/> in <someTag data_value="somevalue"><hr/></someTag>

Comment: you forgot to close your <div>

Comment: @brijmcq sry.. my typo.. i updated question :)

Comment: Just a suggestion use external template

Comment: @santoshsingh well i have to for now... But this shouldn't be the scenerio...

Answer (score 1):

You are having an opening `div` tag modify it to closing `</div>`

```
<someTag data_value="somevalue" class="card">
    <div class="some" *ngFor='let item of tempData'>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.id }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.name }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.status }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.sent }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.views }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.clicks }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.source }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.created }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue" class="text-align-center">
            <span class="fs-6">{{ item.report }}</span>
        </someTag>
        <someTag data_value="somevalue"><hr></someTag>
    </div> ------------------- here
</someTag>
```

Comment: @Aravind  Nice catch

Comment: @HimanshuBansal it should work when you are changing this. any other issue?

Comment: @Aravind actually it was a typo when i write in the question.. it is closed div in the code..

Answer (score 0):

```
<someTag data_value="somevalue" class="card">
   <some-list [data]="tempData">
   </some-list> -------------------add closing tag
</someTag>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is `<hr>` tag on last `<someTag>`, remove it and it will works.
I'm looking for a reason about it, I don't know if it is a angualar2+ bug.

I have had the same problem and I resolved it with a div with css.

```
<someTag data_value="somevalue"><div class="horizontal_line"></div></someTag>
```